# Print symbol with superscript tag in input box

Tags: javascript, html

How can I print the registration symbol with a superscript tag in HTML input?

Below here is what i tried,

```html
<input type="text" value="brand<sup>&#174;</sup>
" id="name" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
```

```
<input type="text" value="brand<sup>&#174;</sup> id="name" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
```

Comment: You can't use HTML tags in attributes of other tags. You won't be able to make one part of the field value superscript and the others not.

Comment: Would you like to use this as a placeholder? After the user clicks make the text disappear?

Comment: @Asks no i want it to stay there

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to create an element and make it editable, for example:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 6px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true">brand<sup>&#174;</sup>&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question of CSS, can you give me the solution for the same? I'm asking about your deleted question.